# Pointwise convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n\sqrt{1+nx}}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, pointwise-convergence

Given this series :
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n*\sqrt{1+nx}}
$$
I have to prove for  which $x \geq 0$  the series converges pointwise.
if $x=0$ the series is :

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)^n$$

and this series converges.

If I assume that $x\neq 0$  I don't find the convergence.
How can I proceed? Do I have to consider a majorant series?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do I have to consider a majorant series? YES. this series is smaller than $$\sum_n \frac{1}{2^n}$$ which is convergent, thus it converges for all $x \ge 0$.

Comment: ok you're right @Crostul